# How to embed a static library into a shared library?

Tags: linux, linker, static-linking, dynamic-linking, undefined-symbol

On linux I am trying to create a shared library, libbar.so, that embeds a commercial static library (licensing is fine). The commercial library has 4 versions: libfoo-seq.a, libfoo-mt.a, libfoo-seq.so, and libfoo-mt.so (they all provide the same symbols, just the code is sequential/multi-threaded, and the lib is static/shared). Of these four I want my code always to use the sequential foo library, so when I create libbar.so I link together my object files and libfoo-seq.a.

The problem is that the users of my library may have already pulled in libfoo-mt.so by the time they pull in my libbar.so, thus all symbols from libfoo are already present by the time libbar.so is read in, so my calls to the functions in foo are resolved to the multithreaded version.

I wonder how can I resolve this issue? What kind of magic flags do I need to use when I compile to create my object files and when I link my object files with libfoo-seq.a to create libbar.so?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can hide libfoo's symbols in libbar via version script:

```
$ cat libbar.map
{
  global: libbar_*;
  local: libfoo_*;
};
$ gcc ... -o libbar.so -Wl,--version-script=libbar.map
```

Comment: My understanding is that with this the functions of libfoo embedded into my libbar.so would not be visible outside. But that's only one side of the equation. I also need that if the functions of libfoo are already pulled in by opening libfoo-mt.so, then they would not "seep in" into libbar.so when that is opened, and libbar.so would still use the functions from libfoo-seq.a. Would that part also be true?

Comment: Yes, if libfoo's symbols are hidden (via script above) your library will no longer try to import them from outside (and thus they won't be overwritable). You can verify libfoo's binary interface via `readelf -hS --dyn-syms`.

Comment: That sounds good, I'll try it later today. In the meantime... do you happen to know the equivalent of this on Windows and on AIX... :-) ?

Comment: Windows should not have this issue (symbols are already hidden there by default unless you mark them with `declspec(dllexport)`). No AIX expertise but if I read [this](https://developer.ibm.com/articles/au-aix-symbol-visibility/) correctly it supports version scripts like Linux.

Comment: Your solution did work, thanks. But I have found an even simpler for my case: just add "--exclude-libs ALL" to the link line, that will make all embedded static libs local.