# How to embed a static library into a shared library - on OSX

Tags: macos, linker, static-linking, dynamic-linking

I have asked [this question on linux](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56223624/how-to-embed-a-static-library-into-a-shared-library), but now I need the same info on macos... The question is (adapted to macos):

I am trying to create a shared library, libbar.dylib, that embeds a commercial static library (licensing is fine). The commercial library has 4 versions: libfoo-seq.a, libfoo-mt.a, libfoo-seq.dylib, and libfoo-mt.dylib (they all provide the same symbols, just the code is sequential/multi-threaded, and the lib is static/shared). Of these four I want my code always to use the sequential foo library, so when I create libbar.dylib I link together my object files and libfoo-seq.a.

The problem is that the users of my library may have already pulled in libfoo-mt.dylib by the time they pull in my libbar.dylib, thus all symbols from libfoo are already present by the time libbar.dylib is read in, so my calls to the functions in foo are resolved to the multithreaded version. At least I think this is happening. Is there any way to double check?

If this is really what is happening, I wonder how can I resolve this issue? What kind of magic flags do I need to use when I compile to create my object files and when I link my object files with libfoo-seq.a to create libbar.dylib?